# expected identifier or '(' after zipping on a windows machine

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

**Background**

I brought a project down from a GIT repository to a windows machine, zipped it up, and put it on a Google drive.
I then pulled it down to my Mac, unzipped it and where it worked before on my other Mac, I am now getting the following error.

```html
/Users/myname/Desktop/cmh.pubweb.theapp/TheApp/TheApp-Bridging-Header.h:1:9: note: in file included from /Users/myname/Desktop/cmh.pubweb.theapp/TheApp/TheApp-Bridging-Header.h:1:
#import <Google/Analytics.h>
        ^
/Users/myname/Desktop/cmh.pubweb.theapp/Pods/Headers/Public/Google/Google/Analytics.h:1:1: error: expected identifier or '('
../../../../Google/Headers/Analytics.h
^
<unknown>:0: error: failed to import bridging header '/Users/myname/Desktop/cmh.pubweb.theapp/TheApp/TheApp-Bridging-Header.h'
```

**Notables**
- I am running this on xcode 9.1 whereas my other Mac had an earlier version.
- It was written in Swift 3.

**What I have done**

1. Read just about every example of this error on Stackoverflow and applied suggestions without success.
2. Hit google and found one example where someone had an issue with windows doing something to one of the files.  I didn't quite understand what they were getting at and applying the suggested fix didn't work out.
3. I have deleted the entire build folder.
4. I have performed "Clean Build Folder" without success.

I hesitate to post this as it seems to be a very vague error that has been tackled from a dozen different directions but I am at a loss after a day of trying to hunt this down.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The general practice is to only commit the `Podfile` to the repository and not the `Pod folder`. If that is the case, you will need to setup `Pods` on your new mac. Make sure you have `cocoapods` installed and setup on your new mac and then run `pod install` in your project directory

Answer (score 0):

Based partially on the answer posted by @Malik

- Deleted the POD directory in the root of the project folder
- Deleted the Podfile.lock file. (left Podfile in place)
- Downloaded CocoaPods App https://cocoapods.org/app  (this was due to running into cert expiration issues even though all expired certs had been removed.  Seems the app deals with it.)
- Installed CocoaPods to the target app.
- Also changed the project explicite location in the PodFile to reflect the current location in my system.

This resolved the current issues.